# Developing interactive GIS application?

Tags: web-gis

I'm developing an interactive web (HTM5) gis application wich the user draw an element (circle for example) and extract data from base map (OpenStreetMap).The features would be:

1º Base Map like OSM.
2º Control panel to draw a circle (in leaflet.draw).
3º Representation of selected objects within this circle area.
4º Save the selected objects into a variable.

The application would focus on census data where the user gets the number of people within that area.

Comment: You, please, should clarify your question. What do you want exactly? Is there any need of including QGIS in your web-app? Why do you want to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use QGIS for making this extraction. QGIS is IMHO not best choice for it, you need something, which you can use in batch. GRASS GIS or some custom script using OGR or PostGIS can do this easily.

You are probably looking for WPS interface, which is intended to perform tasks like this. There are several options around: PyWPS, Zoo-project, Geoserver, deegree, 52North to name the most known one.

At the background, most of them can talk to GRASS GIS or enable you to program what ever analysis you need to perform (such as data extraction).

You should probably load the OSM data to database first, to have better performance.